# Angular UI grid: notify user that sort may take a while

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

We're using Angular UI grid to fetch and display a large dataset that can sometimes take a while to sort. We've settled on warning the user of this when they click the sort button.

So we're using:

```
gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, function(){
    $scope.notificationList = sharedFunctionsService.addNotification('Warning', 'Sorting may take a while to complete', $scope.notificationList);
});
```

We've also tried using angular bootstrap alerts. But either way, what happens is the user clicks the sort button, the sort completes and then the message appears. I know this is some async operation, but how can I tell Angular/Node to execute the notification first? Or, if there's some other way, I'd be happy to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `on.sortChanged` event, which only fires after the sort is completed. Try instead to use an `onClick` event, which would fire as soon as the button is clicked, and before the sort occurs.

Comment: When I put a `console.log()` statement in `on.sortChanged` it fired immediately. But also, I don't see `onClick` in the API. How can use `onClick` to trigger when any sort ascending or sort descending button is pushed?

Comment: It wouldn't be a grid event, it would be a native javascript event (or Angular UI).

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to get at that button with an native javascript `onClick`. I did try editing the header template `headerCellTemplate` to fire a function but that didn't seem to work either.